# Checking the completeness of a given space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be the vector space of all real sequences with finite support (i.e., there are only finitely many non-zero elements) with the scalar product
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_iy_i
$$
for all $x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n, \ldots), y=(y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n, \ldots)\in X$. Checking $X$ is a Hilbert space or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let

$$x^{(n)}_k=\begin{cases}
\frac1k,&\text{if }1\le k\le n\\\\
0,&\text{if }k>n\;.
\end{cases}$$

Is $\left\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$ Cauchy? Has it a limit in $X$?

Comment: Dear Sir. Thank you for your interesting example.

Comment: @blindman: You’re very welcome.